# add gtk.widget in a gnome Applet

Tags: python, applet, gtk, gnome

I have a question :

I write a little gnome applet, and when we click on a button i want to add a gtk.widget under  the "gnome-panel" like the calendar of the clock-applet.

But I don't know how to do this.
It's my code :

```
listButton = gtk.Button(_("lastest"))
self.listTwitt = gtk.TreeView()
mainLayout = gtk.VBox()
mainLayout.pack_start(listButton)
mainLayout.pack_start(self.listTwitt)
self.applet.add(mainLayout)
```

With this code, when i click on the button, the list shows up in the gnome panel : it's because I add it in the mainLayout.

So how do I add it under the "gnome-panel".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `gtk.Window`, position it under the applet, and add it in there.

Comment: And how to position this window? After all, the applet might be at the top or the bottom of the screen, and maybe even at the sides.

Comment: A panel applet is a widget too, so you can get its size and position.